# use any curve to connect two certain points with certain link length using javascript of its library such as d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to connect two point using a curve, we know the coordinates of start point, the coordinates of end point, curve length. Since the length is greater than the direct straight line of the two points, a curve should be used. Any method using the d3 library would be better. I found something similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445260/javascript-canvas-curve-with-fixed-length). But the question is not actually solved since calculating the length is far too complex. Thanks.

Here is one way of using circle arc, I analytically try it but it seems not good enough since we need some numerical method such as Newton's method to obtain theta, the function has the form

sin theta / theta = 2l / s

where l is the length of the curve and s is the length of the straight line (segment).

Comment: It's gone 3AM and I'm probably tired, but aren't there an infinite number of such curves?

Comment: You work so late!! Yes, you are correct. I am thinking about some curve that look good. Also I have some problem with the implementation using d3 library. I will edit my question and post some code. If you have time, please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: the curve that satisfies the condition is an arc. Given points, and desired curve length, finding such arc is a matter of high school math. Since you didn't bother attaching a jsfiddle or similar prototype showing some effort from your side, I won't bother too.

Comment: I did try the method of arc but it is not that simple as it looks. I just edited my question. In order to obtain the circle length you need some numerical method such as Newton's method. I have some simple code for a simpler one and I will add to the question later. Thanks.

Comment: Try half-elipse, if arc is too difficult.